# How to preserve CSS transition in react child component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm facing this issue in which if I don't wrap an element with CSS transition into a React child component then it runs the transition smoothly and if I wrap it into a child component it doesn't show the transition at all.

App.js

```
...

const [pb, setPb] = React.useState("0");

if (pb == 0) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setPb("60");
  }, 1000);
}

const AnotherBall = () => {
  return (
    <div
      className="ball2"
      style={{
        top: `${pb}%`
      }}
    ></div>
  );
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <div
      className="ball"
      style={{
        top: `${pb}%`
      }}
    ></div>
    <AnotherBall />
  </div>
);
```

style.css

```
...

.ball,
.ball2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ff5f5f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.ball2 {
  left: 90%;
  background: #ff5f5f;
}
```

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-wescoff-jcxgw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare components inside the body of other components. Every time a component rerenders the functions it contains are redeclared, meaning they are not referentially stable from one render to the next. `AnotherBall` in your example is being unmounted and remounted with the new value because React thinks it's a new component.

Instead, move the component outside of `App` and pass the required value as a prop like this:

```
// App.js

<AnotherBall pb={pb} />
```

```
// AnotherBall.js

const AnotherBall = ({pb}) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="ball2"
      style={{
        top: `${pb}%`
      }}
    ></div>
  );
};
```